# DelayQueue not working at all, messages are sent right away

Tags: python, python-3.x, message-queue, telegram-bot

I got a simple "Hello!" message sender through Telegram API that is not respecting the message limits of the queue I put the messages through. It should send 1 message at each second: **burst_limit=2, time_limit_ms=2034**

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telegram.ext import DelayQueue

client = TelegramClient ('Social BOT', api_id_social, api_hash_social,update_workers=50,spawn_read_thread=True)
dqueue1 = DelayQueue(burst_limit=2, time_limit_ms=2034)

for inputUser in inputUsers:
        msg = "Hello!"
        try: 
                dqueue1(client.send_message,inputUser,msg)
    except DelayQueueError:
        print ("CRITICAL - DelayQueueError")
    except PeerFloodError:
        print ("CRITICAL - PeerFloodError - SPAM")
```

Happens that it does't delay at all. All the messages were sent right away not respecting the **burst_limit** and **time_limit_ms** parameters (Look at the messages sent time at the log below):

```
2018-03-16 01:54:07,133 - telethon.telegram_bare_client - DEBUG - Invoking SendMessageRequest
2018-03-16 01:54:07,133 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Sending requests with IDs: SendMessageRequest: 6533354988211365228
2018-03-16 01:54:07,196 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Processing Remote Procedure Call result
2018-03-16 01:54:07,196 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Received response for request with ID 6533354988211365228
2018-03-16 01:54:07,196 - telethon.telegram_bare_client - DEBUG - Invoking SendMessageRequest
2018-03-16 01:54:07,197 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Sending requests with IDs: SendMessageRequest: 6533354988465059764
2018-03-16 01:54:07,282 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Processing Remote Procedure Call result
2018-03-16 01:54:07,282 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Received response for request with ID 6533354988465059764
2018-03-16 01:54:09,318 - telethon.telegram_bare_client - DEBUG - Invoking SendMessageRequest
2018-03-16 01:54:09,318 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Sending requests with IDs: SendMessageRequest: 6533354997542220840
2018-03-16 01:54:09,396 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Processing Remote Procedure Call result
2018-03-16 01:54:09,396 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Received response for request with ID 6533354997542220840
2018-03-16 01:54:09,397 - telethon.telegram_bare_client - DEBUG - Invoking SendMessageRequest
2018-03-16 01:54:09,398 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Sending requests with IDs: SendMessageRequest: 6533354997858894120
2018-03-16 01:54:09,457 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Processing Remote Procedure Call result
2018-03-16 01:54:09,457 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Received response for request with ID 6533354997858894120
2018-03-16 01:54:11,494 - telethon.telegram_bare_client - DEBUG - Invoking SendMessageRequest
2018-03-16 01:54:11,494 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Sending requests with IDs: SendMessageRequest: 6533355006835881248
2018-03-16 01:54:11,561 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Processing Remote Procedure Call result
2018-03-16 01:54:11,561 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Received response for request with ID 6533355006835881248
2018-03-16 01:54:11,561 - telethon.telegram_bare_client - DEBUG - Invoking SendMessageRequest
2018-03-16 01:54:11,562 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Sending requests with IDs: SendMessageRequest: 6533355007105024352
2018-03-16 01:54:11,630 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Processing Remote Procedure Call result
2018-03-16 01:54:11,630 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Received response for request with ID 6533355007105024352
2018-03-16 01:54:13,667 - telethon.telegram_bare_client - DEBUG - Invoking SendMessageRequest
2018-03-16 01:54:13,667 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Sending requests with IDs: SendMessageRequest: 6533355016117365140
2018-03-16 01:54:13,746 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Processing Remote Procedure Call result
2018-03-16 01:54:13,746 - telethon.network.mtproto_sender - DEBUG - Received response for request with ID 6533355016117365140
```

What can be happening or what am I forgetting here?

Comment: Somehow, it started working again. I moved all the script to another file with just the basic that is needed to reproduce this, and it ran OK.